# Cannot Parse XML when ampersand is in CDATA

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, cdata

I am receiving an xml payload via message queue.  The xml payload is being serialized (including the CDATA tags) which appears to be causing our parsers to break.  Can the CDATA tags be serialized like other xml elements and still be handled appropriately?

Our data is coming through as shown below and breaking when we try to deserialize it:

```
&lt;![CDATA[ message json with & ]]&gt;
```

**EDIT (Error we are getting):**

```
The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'ProcessMqMessage'. Character reference not valid. Line 1, position 113951.
```

Any suggestions or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any control over the source of the data? Whoever is generating this XML needs to be told to encode their output.

Comment: This is just HTML encoded.  Couldnt you run a decode on it before attempting to parse?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I believe it has something to do with the IBM MQ libraries both sides are using.  Those libraries are serializing the xml (I believe) and is maybe part of the issue.

Comment: @paqogomez we are using IBM MQ libraries that pull the messages off of the queue so it is breaking prior to our app getting a hold of it...unfortunately :(

Comment: So where do you anticipate putting the fix?

Comment: @ paqogomez I was just trying to confirm that what I supplied in my question is invalid...sounds like it is and won't be interpreted correctly.

Comment: If your question is whether the unescaped ampersand is allowed and valid XML within the CDATA section, then the answer is yes.

Comment: So what I posted above is valid and the text between CDATA would not be parsed? Meaning, the serialized characters around CDATA should not cause an issue and the CDATA portion should be interpreted correctly?

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me exactly what you mean by 'parsed'. What's the actual error you are getting?

Comment: I updated the question with the error we are getting which appears to be related to the data in the CDATA portion being parsed.  It seems like the CDATA is being ignored and the data is being parse which is causing it to break because there is an ampersand in the data.

Comment: @scarpacci - yes `&lt;![CDATA[` is not beginning of CDATA section (must be `<![CDATA[`) and as result it is parsed as plain text content (and hence fail on `&`).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thank you for the input! I was worried that was the case.